# Jmeter - Until request gets success execute max. 60 requests in 5 minutes with 5 seconds pause

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

I have one request, which triggers every 5 seconds and maximum for 5 minutes until it gets 200 in response code. So ideally that request executes 12 times in a minute and 60 requests total if it fails everytime.

My problem is how I define those maximum 60 requests.

*Here is my configuration*

I have taken one While Controller

```
${__javaScript(parseInt(vars.get("Response_code"))!=200)}
```

**In that while controller this components are there,**

- While Controller

  - User Defined Variable `(Response_code)`
  - Counter `(Starting value: 1, Increment:1, Maximum Value:60)`
  - My HTTP Request

    - JSR223 PostProcessor `(vars.put("Response_code",prev.getResponseCode());)`
    - Constant Throughput Timer `(Targer throughput: 12.0)`

Where should I have to put condition like if my HTTP request gets success in 3rd attempt go ahead to next request else repeat that request again after 5 seconds till 5 minutes?

I am using jmeter Ver. 5.5

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can amend your While Controller's condition to look like:

   ```
    ${__javaScript((parseInt(vars.get("Response_code"))!=200 && ${counter} < 60),)}
   ```

   this way it will loop until response code is 200 but not more than 60 times.
2. Instead of Constant Throughput Timer you can use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to introduce static delay of 5000 ms.
3. There is no need to have a counter, [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) exposes a special variable, in your case it will be `${__jm__While Controller For Thumbnail-1 QA1.pdf__idx}`

More information: [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter)